# SFML C++ Text invalid free / delete

Tags: c++, linux, sfml

I'm currently using the SFML 2.4.2-1 on arch linux and i'm having some troubles with the Text.

I'm compiling with `g++` (I also tried with `clang++`).

I isolated my example and got that code which crash everytime:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  sf::RenderWindow win(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "Arcade sfml");
  sf::Font font;

  if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
    {
      throw std::exception();
    }

  sf::Text text("oui", font);

  win.draw(text);
  win.display();
  sleep(10000);
  win.close();
}
```

The Text destructor crash with an invalid free / delete.

Here is the valgrind output:

```
==6297== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x6458 with no size/direction hints.
==6297==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==6297==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
==6297== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6297==    at 0x4C2C20A: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6297==    by 0x401D75: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<sf::Vertex>::deallocate(sf::Vertex*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==6297==    by 0x401D43: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<sf::Vertex> >::deallocate(std::allocator<sf::Vertex>&, sf::Vertex*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:442)
==6297==    by 0x401CE3: std::_Vector_base<sf::Vertex, std::allocator<sf::Vertex> >::_M_deallocate(sf::Vertex*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:178)
==6297==    by 0x401C4D: std::_Vector_base<sf::Vertex, std::allocator<sf::Vertex> >::~_Vector_base() (stl_vector.h:160)
==6297==    by 0x401BDC: std::vector<sf::Vertex, std::allocator<sf::Vertex> >::~vector() (stl_vector.h:427)
==6297==    by 0x401ABF: sf::VertexArray::~VertexArray() (VertexArray.hpp:45)
==6297==    by 0x401B32: sf::Text::~Text() (Text.hpp:48)
==6297==    by 0x4016CB: main (main.cpp:15)
==6297==  Address 0x6031b0 is 16 bytes inside data symbol "_ZTVN2sf11VertexArrayE"
```

I can't understand why it keep crashing with that same error. Also when I execute with valgrind, the program itself work properly, by that I mean the text is printed a intended, but that error remain, and make the program crash when executed alone.

**Edit:**

g++ version: `g++ (GCC) 6.3.1 20170109`

clang++ version: `clang version 3.9.1 (tags/RELEASE_391/final)`

For my project, I compile a shared library, but for that example it was a simple executable:

Shared library:

```
-fPIC -std=c++14 -W -Wall -Wextra -shared -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio
```

Simple executable:

```
-std=c++14 -W -Wall -Wextra -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Comment: How is that text displayed when you're not calling display?

Comment: I did not used it in my example because I forgot and the problem is not here. My program crash and I can't understand why.

Comment: What is the version of g++ you are using? and was the SFML libraries you are using the same version?   Or did you recompile the SFML libraries yourself and are using those libraries?  Can you also provide the build command you are using to build this?

Comment: I just added the command line and versions. I'm using the Arch version of the SFML, downloaded on the official repositories with `pacman`.

Comment: I dont see where you are using the -I command with the directory to your SFML installation or the -L to your library location...  but that prolly isnt the issue since it is compiling...

Comment: That is because the files are installed in `/usr/lib/` directory, I will investigate more..

Comment: Alright, so after reviewing your question again, I am wondering if there is an issue going on with the ABI of the libraries,  over the different versions of c++ the ABI has  changed, so for example if you are compiling with `c++14` and the installed library you have was compiled using `c++11` that could cause the inexplainable crash.  Can you download SFML, and compile it?  The website says the windows build is compatible with GCC 6.1 which by default uses `std=gnu14`.  I didn't see the version of c++ used for the linux version.  But I did see mac is only c++11.

Comment: Another thing you can attempt is to make sure you are compiling for 64bit as the SFML documentation states the linux release is only 64bit and you will have to compile the 32bit libraries yourself.